# Apache Flink Stream with feedback loop

Tags: apache-flink

How can I implement a feedback loop in Flink stream.  In other words, how can I write a SinkFunction that is also SourceFunction?

```
DataStream<Control> controlSignal = ..
DataStream<Data> dataStream = ...

DataStream<Output>  outputStream = controlSignal
.connect(dataSignal)
.flapMap(FlatMapFunction)
```

Now, I want send the outputStream to a sink AND also based on some logic send data to ControlStream.

One way to do it is for ControlStream to read from external system like Kafka and I can outputStream to Kafka topic and that'll do the job. But it seems odd to use external system if I just want to feedback from end of the stream to beginning of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an [iteration](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/datastream_api.html#iterations). One common approach to iterating the control signal is to use a [side output](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/side_output.html) with `Control` data from the function (in your case it would have to be a `CoProcessFunction`) that you then use to close the iteration.

One challenge is often that the control stream wants to be broadcast, while the data stream is partitioned for parallel processing. Flink 1.5 supports connecting keyed and broadcast streams, older versions don't.

Comment: Iterations do have one significant flaw, which is that Flink cannot provide processing guarantees for jobs with iterators, as the checkpointing mechanism can't be guaranteed to correctly capture all of the state. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/state/checkpointing.html#state-checkpoints-in-iterative-jobs for more details.

Comment: Using side output is a excellent suggestion and I will use that. I am still not sure if I should use iteration or just send the side output with control data to the kakfa topic which is the source of the control stream.